# We are discussing useful things. We are discussing on useful things

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

We are discussing useful things .We are discussing on useful things. 
Which is the correct answer? Can we use the "on"here?

Answer (score 3):

We are discussing umbrellas.

We are having a discussion on umbrella design.

Comment: Please explain it easily.

Comment: We cannot use "on" with the verb "to discuss".  We discuss it, not *on it.

Comment: *On* is used only with the noun, not the verb.

Comment: But , You wrote in your sentences.We are having a discussion on umbrella design.

Comment: [***discuss***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/discuss) is a transitive verb, so a direct object is needed. A prepositional phrase (such as "on useful things") does not qualify.